# Big-O Notation of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} c \cdot x_i$ vs. $c \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

We have the following two algorithms and need to determine the big O-notation:

Algorithm 1
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c \cdot x_i $$

Algorithm 2
$$  c \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $$

Although I studied the topic some hours, I am not really comfortable with the analysis of algorithm, so I would be happy, if you could give me some inputs on it:

I started with the second one, as it looks easier to me. If we have an array of length n we sum over every element so that would give O(n). Then we multiply once with a constant c. Now I am struggling with the analysis. Does that mean that we add 1 to our big O notation, hence O(n+1)? But I learned that we can drop constants so that would lead us back to O(n).

The second algorithm was more difficult to me. I think it takes longer to execute it, because every element in the array is multiplied with c and only then we can add it to the sum. So intuitively I would say that we double the effort. The best idea I can come up with, would be O(2n). As every step element in the array is multiplied and summed up. But also here we can drop the constant, right? So it would also be O(n).

I would be happy, if you could help me, streamline my thoughts in the right direction. The exercise suggests that they yield the same result, but differ in their complexity, so my analysis must somehow be wrong.

The exercise also suggests to think about time and space complexity, which it denotes as T and O. Now suppose we find that both would be O(n), what is then T? Or in general, what is difference between those two in this specific example?

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generally correct, but off by one in some of your calculations.

1. In the first algorithm, you have $n$ multiplications (you multiply each of the $n$ numbers by $c$), followed by $n-1$ additions (remember, to add $n$ numbers, you only need $n-1$ additions! The addition of the second to the first, then the addition of the third to the result, and so on). So in total, you have $n+n-1 = 2n-1$ operations. This is, of course, an element of $O(n)$.
2. In the second algorithm, you have $n-1$ additions plus one multiplication, so you need $n$ operations again, and the whole job is again in $O(n)$.

---

You are completely incorrect here though:

> The exercise suggests that they yield the same result, but differ in their complexity, so my analysis must somehow be wrong.

This is not true. Two algorithms can have the same big-o complexity yet one can be vastly faster than the other.

Comment: Very useful, thank you a lot! And could you quickly explain, what the difference between time and space complexity is our case? The exercise denotes it as T and O. How can I derive T, if we now know that both algorithms are O(n)?

Comment: @MarlonBrando There is no simple connection converting time and space complexity. For space complexity, you need to do the same steps as with time complexity, just that you have to count the amount of storage space you are using up instead of the number of operations you are doing. In your particular case, you should find both algorithms require only a single variable to store the temporary result (plus, of course, $n$ variables to hold the input...)

Comment: Alright, so if I understand correctly, what we just did with the Big O notation is analyzing the time complexity? And the space complexity is to look out for what we need to store in our memory?

Comment: @MarlonBrando More or less. What we did was we found the big O of the time complexity, and similarly, you can find the big O of spatial complexity.